# Designing two tables in MySQL to use in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, orm, relational-database

I would like to design two tables as follows, my question is, if this design is correct.

table tweet: tweet_id,...
tweet table needs 0..* hashtags -> table hashtags : hashtag_id,tweet_id,hashtag

I would like to use them in JPA, so i think that I will need primary key for both of the tables.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want a completely normalised schema for this you should not have the text of the hashtag repeated mulitple times across many tweets.

In other words, you should have 3 tables:

```
Tweet table
    tweet_id
    tweet_text

Tweet_Hashtag table (this is purely a join table)
    tweet_id
    hashtag_id

Hashtag table
    hashtag_id
    hashtag_text
```

So a tweet has many tweet_hashtag's, and a hashtag has many tweet_hashtag's.

It is a many-to-many relationship between tweet and hashtag.

However, in the real world, it would be unlikely that a separate hashtag table would be created as their use in Twitter is limited to 139 characters, and creating a (global) unique ID system would be difficult. So a hashtag's text would likely be used as it's unique key anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct: there is a one to many relationship between the tweet and the hashtags.